# "Azure Subscrtiption is not registered with CDN Provider". How do I register this? Where do I register?

Tags: azure

I was trying to create a CDN Profile but when I do I get this message "Azure Subscrtiption is not registered with CDN Provider"

Answer (score 2):

this probably means you need to [register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-register-provider-errors) CDN provider for you.

```
Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.CDN
```

Alternatively, you can use Portal: go to subscriptions >> pick target subscription >> resource providers >> find provider in the list and register it